# Subform text fields show #Name? instead of data from ADO-recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

In response to comments:

I built up a new form `sfrmService` from scratch --> getting `#Name?` again  :-(
I built it with form-assistant, taking the field-names from a table. ControlSources therefore match, because I named fields in my `rs` accordingly.

`? Me.pID.ControlSource` yields `pID`, same for `pTitel`, name is correct

I added a routine to fill `rs` with 1 row (see below), and `? rs.RecordCount` yields `1`

Bigger picture: In a booking-system, I collect data for a new booking over 3 sequential forms. `sfrmService` (subform on 1 of these 3 forms) holds a list of services to be linked to that new booking.
Of course, I restricted the textfields to only 2, there are more in the original subform. I created a subform with only those 2 textfields for testing, though.
Only when the user commits the newly created booking, the data will be written to the tables. 
I want to do these operations in-memory with disconnected recordsets. I could write them directly to the tables, but would need to update them every so often and delete them in case of cancel --> resource usage.
And: I'd like to challenge myself to learn new techniques :-)

---

I have a main-form `frmBooking` with a subform `sfrmService`, both are unbound and no links between them defined.

The recordset is built up in the subform's `onload`-Event like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public rs As ADODB.Recordset

...

Private Sub Form_Load()

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  With rs
    .Fields.Append "pID", adInteger, 4, adFldKeyColumn
    .Fields.Append "pTitel", adVarChar, 255, adFldUpdatable
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Open
  End With

  ' *** added with 1st update of question ***
  rs.AddNew
  rs!pID = 100
  rs!pTitel = "test"
  rs.Update
  rs.MoveFirst

  Set Me.Recordset = rs

End Sub
```

The recordset is built correctly without errors. It is then filled with data by a routine in the main-form, all is working fine, but the textboxes on `sfrmService` show `#Name?` instead.

I tried to re-bind the controls of the subform with VBA, no difference.
I added `rs.CursorType = adOpenKeySet` before opening the rs, no difference.

I'm just beyond my means here, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Working with MS Access 2019 64-Bit

Comment: What is the ControlSource for each of those text boxes? What number of rows are returned in the rs?  Is "pTitel" spelled correctly?

Comment: Id be curious to know why you arent checking for empty recordsets? Is there a chance it is empty? Also, why are you assigning textbox values this way? Can the form not be bound? It just seems like a lot of work just to display data on a control on a form. It would also be helpful to see more details of your situation.

Comment: @DougCoats sfrm is bound to disconnected rs. Useful to fill combos on conti-frm with low resource usage or create rs without db (e.g list of files in folder on form).  Quite sure textbox.ControlSource is wrong.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher IDK, using recordsets for this just seems out of place. I would rather update the recordsource SQL to limit what you pull in and use bound controls. It might be a style difference, granted, but recordsets are the worst. There is most certainly a better approach.

Comment: @DougCoats I see your point, and I would resort to bound forms if necessary. I think the concept of disconnected in-memory recordsets has a lot of potential for a variety of applications, and I'd like to master that.

Comment: @Michi fair, knowing how is important, so please disregard my comments as they appear to be discouraging. Let me ask a few questions to make sure I understand exactly what you are doing. 1. You are using a recordset to fill the form on load, yes? And as an extension to that question, you are filling a recordset from nothing it looks like, right?  2. The issue is after filling the recordset youre having issues assigning values to controls? Sorry to ask dumb questions but Im making sure I understand the issue 100%

Comment: IM thinking this might be an issue with referencing the control that is the subform. Can you try this? Me!Subform1.SourceObject (obviously replace the subform1 with the name of the subform).

Comment: @DougCoats, binding a form to a rs is out of place ;) He just uses Adodb, not DAO and the rs is disconnected, but you can connect to a db at anytime (just set `rs. ActiveConnection' ). Useful pattern to creater a temp table without the need to compact after deletion.

Comment: @DougCoats the code above is in `sfrmService`, and the problem persists when I open `sfrmService`as main form, so I can rule out the issue you brought up.

Comment: @DougCoats ok, this is what I do: when loading `sfrmService', I create a `ADODB.Recordset` with the fields I need, add 1 row of sample data, and assign the Recordset to `sfrmService.Recordset`. This should now display the rows in the textboxes `pID` and `pTitel`, but instead `#Name?` appears...

Comment: @ComputerVersteher unfortunately no difference with `Me.pID.ControlSource = "pID"` etc.

Comment: And you have to set`CountrolSource` after you assigned the forms new rs! Design-View is not valid, vba needed!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205157/discussion-between-michi-and-computerversteher).

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh!!!! It is working!!!!! Errr, I discovered a seemingly innocent `Me.Requery` after the `Set Me.Recordset = rs' that I had not commented out. When I removed that, it started working like a charm!

Comment: THANKS TO ALL, and a happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

I find it a bit embarassing, but I'll post it anyway so it might be of value to other people fighting a similar battle...

Contrary to my code in the question, I had a `Me.Requery` after the `Set Me.Recordset = rs` that I forgot to comment out...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  With rs
    .Fields.Append "pID", adInteger, 4, adFldKeyColumn
    .Fields.Append "pTitel", adVarChar, 255, adFldUpdatable
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Open
  End With

  Set Me.Recordset = rs
  Me.Requery <--------------------- BAD IDEA
End Sub
```

After I deleted the `Me.Requery`, it worked like a charm.

**Thanks to all commenters who shared their ideas, leading finally to the solution!**

Comment: Add`.ControlSource`to be set and you can requery forms bound to adodb recorset swith`Set Me.RecordSet = Me.RecordSet`